# IdentityServer4 Discovery Client Error - Issuer Name Does Not Match Authority

Tags: identityserver4

I am getting the 'Issuer name does not match authority' error because I have an ssl-terminating load balancer in front of my is4 service (i.e. issuer is https://myurl and authority is http://myurl).

What should I do in this situation? The dns names are identical, it is the s in https which is causing the validation failure!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible for your Issuer and Authority to be different, but it requires changes to configuration of the server and the discovery request.

On your Identity Server's startup method, you can set the issuer:

```
var identityServerBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        options.IssuerUri = $"http://myurl:5000";
    }
    else
    {
        options.IssuerUri = $"https://myurl";
    }
})
```

And then in your discovery document request:

```
DiscoveryDocumentRequest discoveryDocument = null;
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == EnvironmentName.Development)
    {
        discoveryDocument = new DiscoveryDocumentRequest()
        {
            Address = "http://myurl:5000",
            Policy = {
                 RequireHttps = false,
                 Authority = "http://myurl:5000",
                 ValidateEndpoints = false
            },
         };
    }
    else
    {
         discoveryDocument = new DiscoveryDocumentRequest()
         {
             Address = "http://myurl:5000",
             Policy = {
                  RequireHttps = false,
                  Authority = "https://myurl",
                  ValidateEndpoints = false
             },
         };
}
var disco = await httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(discoveryDocument);
```

Comment: hi nick, that looks ideal! I also posted the question on the is4 gitter and mackie1001 replied explaining about needing to process forwarded headers which i think is a slightly better solution as i don't then have to set the issuer uri and can allow it to generate as before. i will add in his answer below for anyone who comes across this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your issuer url is `https` however authority url is `http`. Both urls should be exactly same.

Else you can try setting `ValidateIssuerName` property to false. This property decides if `issuer` name has to be identical to `authority` or not. By default it is true -

```
            var discoRequest = new DiscoveryDocumentRequest
            {
                Address = "authority",
                Policy = new DiscoveryPolicy
                {
                    ValidateIssuerName = false,
                },
            };
```

Comment: Hi Aparna, the authority has to remain https as this is how the clients connect to the is4 server i.e. over ssl to the load balancer. How do I make the issuer https also? As far as I am aware, this is generated by is4 but I do not know how it decides whether to put http or https.

Comment: Unfortunately, I added ValidateIssuerName = false and it just got me to the next error which was something to do with invalid endpoints. I then added ValidateEndpoint = false but then I got an invalid_request error. I am currently troubleshooting to figure out what this invalid_request error is. One thing is certain, the exact same code/config/load balancer setup works fine if I am only using http, not https. I am not sure why the validation is done on url and not simply the dns name as the dns name is the important part I would have thought, not the fact whether it is http or https.

Comment: I found the PublicOrigin property, but this only (ironically!) helps with setting the dns name, it does not control the http/s part. I think working on disabling validation in the discovery client is the most pragmatic approach, I just have hit a brick wall today with this invalid_request error :(

Answer (score 0):

answer from mackie1001 on identityserver4 gitter

your load balancer should forward on the original protocol (X-Forwarded-Proto) and you can use that to set the current request scheme to match the incoming request
you'd just need to create a middleware function to do it
Have a read of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.0

for reference this is the code i added to startup:-

```
                app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
                {
                  ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
                });
```

many thanks mackie1001!

Answer (score 0):

if using nginx as the load balancer you will probably need this in service configuration...

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders =
                    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;

                // Only loopback proxies are allowed by default.
                // Clear that restriction because forwarders are enabled by explicit
                // configuration.
                options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
                options.KnownProxies.Clear();
            });
```

and then add this middleware before the identity server middleware

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```